# Android Sdk: BASE64 Encoder/Decoder not importing

Tags: java, android, encryption

So I am trying to implement a string encryption class that I got from [link to code](http://www.digizol.com/2009/10/java-encrypt-decrypt-jce-salt.html)

and when I try to put it into my android project, I receive the following errors:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The import sun cannot be
>   resolved  SimpleProtector.java    /EncryptedSMS/src/com/nsaers/encryptedsms   line
>   7 Java Problem BASE64Decoder cannot be resolved to a
>   type  SimpleProtector.java    /EncryptedSMS/src/com/nsaers/encryptedsms   line
>   29    Java Problem BASE64Encoder cannot be resolved to a
>   type  SimpleProtector.java    /EncryptedSMS/src/com/nsaers/encryptedsms   line
>   21    Java Problem

Any ideas?

Here is my code of the class:

```
package com.nsaers.encryptedsms;

import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class SimpleProtector {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'i', 's',
            'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

    public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
        // SecretKeyFactory keyFactory =
        // SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        // key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyValue));
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: which API level you have?

Comment: I am using android 4.2.2 api, and the eclipse from the latest release from the android sdk bundle.

Comment: @JohnnyWineShirt did you find solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class in the Android SDK instead of `BASE64Encoder` / `BASE64Decoder`. The API may be slightly different, but it'll do what you need.

However, your code will still not be ideal: any time you use `String.getBytes` or a `String` constructor which takes a byte array, you should specify the encoding to use - UTF-8 is probably the most appropriate. Currently you'll use the system default encoding, which *may* be UTF-8 (I've a feeling it always is in Android) but leaves your code pretty brittle.